# Ошибка авторизации Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Установлена laravel 9, при попитке авторизации в контроллере выдает **ошибку**:

```
Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, stdClass given, called in /Users/andrii/Documents/www/budver/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 332
```

**Код контроллера:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Jobs\NeedHelpMailJob;


class MainController extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->get()->first() ;
        if(!auth()->check()) auth()->login($user) ;

        return view('home') ;

    }

}
```

Дамп объекта **$user**:

```
^ {#314 ▼
  +"id": 1
  +"phone": "1111111111"
  +"email": null
  +"type": "client"
  +"is_status": "active"
  +"name": "Test"
  +"avatar": null
  +"email_verified_at": null
  +"about": null
  +"created_at": "2022-06-21 08:48:47"
  +"updated_at": null
}
```

В чем может быть ошыбка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что Вы используете запрос через `DB::table()`, оттуда достается не  конкретная модель, а `stdClass`, для авторизации же нужна модель User которая унаследована от `Authenticatable`, делайте запрос `User::query()->where('id', 1)->first()` и будет все работать.